# IF statement, not sure why its not working C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to fix this for a while. The IF statement is meant to check multiple conditions instead of running through the else if 4 times. The timer is meant to be checked for half time in a soccer match and if it matches any of the times it links to the referee class where it calls half time or full time. Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is my current version of the code:

```
if (diceRoll == 1)
{
    timer[0] = timer[0] + 10; //Adds 10 minutes to the timer

    if (timer[0] == 45 & timer[0] == 50 & timer[0] == 90 & timer[0] == 95) // Checks for half time
    {
        Referee.timerCheck();
    }
    //Continues if it is not half time or full time
    Console.WriteLine(teams[0] + " have lost possession of the ball. It now sits with " + teams[1] + " in the left centre midfield!");
    Console.WriteLine(timer[0] + " minutes have been played.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to roll the dice to see the outcome!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    ALCM();
}
else if (diceRoll == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(teams[0] + " have passed the ball back into the right centre back position!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to roll the dice to see the outcome!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    HRCB();
}
else if (diceRoll == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(teams[0] + " have passed the ball accross into onto the right winger who has a chance to shoot or pass!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to roll the dice to see the outcome!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    HRW();
}
else if (diceRoll == 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine(teams[0] + " have passed the ball forwards into the right striker!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to roll the dice to see the outcome!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    HRS();
}
else if (diceRoll == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(teams[0] + " have passed the ball forwards into the right striker!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to roll the dice to see the outcome!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    HRS();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(teams[0] + " have passed the ball forwards into the right striker!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to roll the dice to see the outcome!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    HRS();
}
```

Comment: Sorry Ed, our edits happened at the same time

Comment: `timer[0]` cannot be equal to 45, 50, 90 and 95 at the same time.

Comment: `if (timer[0] == 45 & timer[0] == 50 & timer[0] == 90 & timer[0] == 95) /` should be OR statement.. I would refactor the code as well as use the debugger..

Comment: Some serious refactoring is needed here.  Keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @maccettura No harm done.

Comment: Also, a single ampersand (&) is a bitwise and operator.

Comment: First of all, the `&` is a bitwise operator and not the boolean operator you are after. You should've used `&&` instead. Second, you need boolean `OR` instead of boolean `AND` which is `||` in C#

Comment: @StevenG1 - probably unrelated to your issue, but do you want to say `timer[0] = timer[0] + 10` ?     If you start at Zero, there's a chance you might jump right over 45 and go right to 50.

Comment: The comments and answers which say that `&` is a bitwise operator on bools are incorrect. `&` is a perfectly legal operator on bools. It is the *eager logical and operator*, as opposed to `&&` which is the *lazy logical and operator*.

Comment: You are ending all six possibilities with the same statements; just move those statements to *after the if* entirely! Only put things in a *conditional* that are *executed conditionally*. Things that are *always* executed should go *outside* a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to be using || (logical OR) (there is no need to use the |, because your equalities have no side effects)

Your statement should be:

`if (timer[0] == 45 || timer[0] == 50 || timer[0] == 90 || timer[0] == 95)`

Comment: Do not think of `&` and `|` as "bitwise" and `&&` and `||` as "logical"; that's an inaccurate and misleading way to think of them.  Think of `&` and `|` as *bitwise on integers, eager on bools*, and `&&` and `||` as *lazy on bools*.

Comment: I always thought && and || were just ways to short circuit the & and | operators, but this was one of the classes I didn't pay attention in.

Comment: Eric's statement is correct. I fell back into C++ for a moment there. However, in this case, the || is more efficient, as it will break out of the evaluation as soon as timer[0] matches one of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets go through this in small pieces:
First you should use *switch* for your diceRoll. It will make it easier to read.

```
switch(diceRoll)
{
    case 1:
      //your code
      break;
    case 2:
      //your code
      break;
}
```

Now, your *if* isn't doing what you expect. You're using **&** instead of **||** (or) that is what you want.
it should be:

```
if (timer[0] == 45 || timer[0] == 50 || timer[0] == 90 || timer[0] == 95)
```

Comment: The backtick is for *inline* code, indent 4 spaces for block code formatting.

Comment: In the Stack Overflow question/answer editor, you can select a block of code and press Ctrl+K to indent it four spaces, so it'll format correctly.

Comment: Thanks guys (@EdPlunkett @crashmstr) I didn't know that.